# How to break line in application / json files?

Tags: json, line-breaks

I have a text and would like to break lines in it, the format is
 application / json.

I used /n but sometimes it seems to work, and other no.

```
{"Text":"# hi  \n\n::: red \n\nImportant  \n bye"}
```

Thanks

Comment: "sometimes it seems to work, and other no.": What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\` for escape character before `\n` :

```
{"Text":"# hi  \\n\\n::: red \\n\\nImportant  \\n bye"}
```

Comment: Thanks. One questions. Do have any chance of the encode remove the line breaks of this string?

Comment: I think different encoding will affect the line break, another way  is that you can use any json parser to parse the json and then add new line into the json, in this way no encoding issue will occur.